# Finding common columns between multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I have hundreds of tables containing 400+ columns each.
I want to find the names of common columns between these tables.
How can I do it. I found a code online which works but only for lesser number of tables.
 When I run the query in my case I get the following error--> 'The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.'

Here is query :

```
insert into temp_table 
  select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'test_datajuly17' 
  intersect select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'test_datajuly20' 
  intersect select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'test_datajuly21'
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: ...which query? I don't see a query

Comment: insert into temp_table

select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'test_datajuly17'
intersect
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'test_datajuly20'
intersect
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'test_datajuly21'

Comment: This is the query for three tables

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Query below does exactly the same thing. So you don't need an inner and outer query.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
  INNER JOIN @TEMPTABLE tt on tt.TableName = isc.TABLE_NAME
  GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below.

If you know the tables you want to compare with, put the table name into a temp table (@TEMPTABLE)  and then do the below

```
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE AS TABLE
(
    TableName VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTo @TEMPTABLE
VALUES
('spt_fallback_dev'), --test names
('spt_values')



SELECT fulllist.*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS fulllist
INNER JOIN @TEMPTABLE baseCmp on baseCmp.TableName = fulllist.TABLE_NAME
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
      INNER JOIN @TEMPTABLE tt on tt.TableName = isc.TABLE_NAME
      GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp on temp.COLUMN_NAME = fulllist.COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Then you can do all sorts of things with the result (such as pivot it etc)

Comment: This query does not give the common columns between the tables

Comment: It just gives all the columns that are present in all the tables.

Comment: Oh I know the problem then, it is the outer query. I can fix that.

Comment: That would be great .

Comment: I have updated the query can you try it out. Note this should give you result where a column is in one or more tables. If you want to find columns that are in all tables then you can change the Having statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, if this answers your question, just make my answer correct.